# Fancy Jquery Animtions similar to Flash website

Tags: jquery

I am trying to recreate the animations used on this site.

http://www.altinhomes.com/

It was originally built in Flash but I want to do a site that uses very similar style of animation on the black sub-headings.

I was wondering if there were any Jquery plugins or ones that could be hacked to do similar animations like show on the sub sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with this example

```
$("#element").animate(
{
    top:'20px'
}, 1000);
```

This moves the `element` 20 pixels downward in 1000 miliseconds

See [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly possible in jQuery or even standard javascript, although granted jQuery may be easier with its `.animate()` functions.

All the submenu is doing is altering its width to be the same width as the content and making the left of the content the same as the left of the button.

This is then all changed over time gradually, this can be done by setting a time in jQuery animate function.

I suggest reading the docs [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)